# zend form giving error when working with modules

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have started learning zend framework. I am using version 1.12. I am using modular approach. I have created one module called 'admin'. Following the my structure of the site

```
application/
   (...other directories)
   modules/
       admin/
          controllers/
             IndexController.php
          forms/
             Login.php
          views/
             scripts/
                (...view scripts)
          Bootstrap.php
```

In this module I have created one form called 'login' using zf tool. whose class is created like this.

```
class Admin_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {

    } 
}
```

now the problem comes when I called this form in my admin module's index controller.

```
class Admin_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction() 
    {   
        $form = new Admin_Form_Login;
     }
}
```

It gives me error like this.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Form_Login' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\novo\application\modules\admin\controllers\IndexController.php on line 13.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. anybody, please help me.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do th enext things:
1. Enable autoloading for module's models:
in application.ini:

```
resources.modules = []
resources.views = []
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH . "/modules"
```

1. Create form in **modules/admin/models/Form/Login.php** and call class **Admin_Model_Form_Login**
2. Check your module bootstrap. It should be:

   class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap